# iphone @property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

What is the difference between these two?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)
@property (nonatomic, copy)
```

What is the other type like this?

Answer (score 6):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW27

Answer (score 6):

Using `retain` is equivalent to this method:

```
- (void)setMyObject:(id)object {
    myObject = [object retain];
}
```

Using `copy` is like this:

```
- (void)setMyObject:(id)object {
    myObject = [object copy];
}
```

The main difference is that there are now two copies of the same object. Now, if you change an instance variable in your class (such as changing `@"A"` to `@"B"`), the original object will stay intact (it will still be `@"A"`).

Comment: Should these methods be named setMyObject?

Comment: Also, the other "type like this" is "assign" which is used to copy primitive types (e.g. int, float, BOOL).

Comment: If you would implement a retaining setter by hand, the one you described is not the way to do it. You should first check the "old" field value and release it if it still has a value. But only do this if the old value is different than the value you're trying to set. Everntually you will have a 4 to 5 line code setter. Once you see that, you will appreciate the @property notation even more! :)

Comment: @Tom van Zummeren - can you please give an example? I am not getting the full power of @property... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, use:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy)
```

..for NSString properties and this for all other object properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)
```

Comment: Actually, since NSString is immutable won't it make more sense to simply use @property (nonatomic, retain) for NSString? Maybe you mean the other way around.

Comment: I think the idea is to make a copy in case the string is actually a mutable string. That way the string won't unexpectedly change on you.

Answer (score 0):

For attributes whose type is an immutable value class that conforms to the NSCopying protocol, you almost always should specify **

> copy

** in your @property declaration. Specifying **

> retain

** is something you almost never want in such a situation.

Since in almost all cases you want to prevent mutating an object's attributes behind its back, you should mark the properties representing them copy. (And if you write the setter yourself instead of using @synthesize you should remember to actually use copy instead of retain in it.)